# How to extract values from one Http request and pass as an array to the next Http Request In Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a list of order number's that I have got from one HTTP request.I need  to extract all these numbers and use in my next HTTP request passing as an array

Comment: This is not a consulting or interview prep site.  Give more details and show the code you have tried yourself. This is needed in order to help you.  Otherwise others will shortly close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, in order to provide exact steps we need:

1. Full (or partial) response for 1st request
2. Exact format of parameter for 2nd request.

In the meantime here is how you can extract the **whole** response into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so you will be able to re-use it somewhere else:

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which response you need to extract
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `response`
   - Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)` (see [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) article for the regex explanation if needed)
   - Template: `$1$`
3. That's it, now you will be able to use the response from the previous request as `${response}` where required.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add a post processor [regular expression extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to your get Http request and extract all order Ids .Use Match no -1 to store all order Ids.Assume that the name of the created variable is **"Orders"**

Step 2: Add a [Beanshell pre-processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to your Post HTTP request and add the following code to the preprocessor

```
int count = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("Orders_matchNr"));

String delimiter = ",";
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++) { 
sb.append(vars.get("Orders_" + i));
if (i == count){
break; //to eliminate comma after the array
 }else {
 sb.append(delimiter);
 }
}
vars.put("arrayOutPut",sb.toString());
```

use **[${arrayOutPut}]** to pass as an array

[image]
[image]

For more information on extracting variables [follow this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-extract-and-re-use-as-variable/)

Comment: Thanks @Rohit
it works for me!!!